# Parse JSON to Java object with dynamics objects in JSON-response

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a JSON-response to a Java object and then I want to save it to a Postgresql.

I have the following json-response:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "FI": "120986750",
            "event_id": "5164306",
            "cards": {
                "updated_at": "1660559432",
                "key": "AAA100",
                "sp": {
                    "cards": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "Cards",
                        "odds": [
                            {
                                "id": "101",
                                "odds": "2.200",
                                "header": "Over",
                                "name": "11"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "102",
                                "odds": "8.500",
                                "header": "Exactly",
                                "name": "11"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "103",
                                "odds": "1.909",
                                "header": "Under",
                                "name": "11"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "corners": {
                "updated_at": "1660559431",
                "key": "AAA200",
                "sp": {
                    "corners": {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "Corners",
                        "odds": [
                            {
                                "id": "201",
                                "odds": "2.200",
                                "header": "Over",
                                "name": "10"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "202",
                                "odds": "8.500",
                                "header": "Exactly",
                                "name": "10"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "203",
                                "odds": "1.909",
                                "header": "Under",
                                "name": "10"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "total_corners": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "name": "Total Corners",
                        "odds": [
                            {
                                "id": "204",
                                "odds": "17.000",
                                "name": "Under 6"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "205",
                                "odds": "4.333",
                                "name": "6 - 8"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "206",
                                "odds": "2.750",
                                "name": "9 - 11"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "207",
                                "odds": "3.400",
                                "name": "12 - 14"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "208",
                                "odds": "5.500",
                                "name": "Over 14"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I started to create a class like this:

```
public class PreMatchOdds {

    @JsonProperty("success")
    private Integer success;
    @JsonProperty("results")
    private List<Result> results = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -8631993296159893856L;

getter and setters..
```

Then instead of

```
    @JsonProperty("cards")
    private Cards cards;

and

    @JsonProperty("corners")
    private Corners corners;
```

I tried with:

```
@JsonProperty("categories")
@JsonAlias({"cards", "corners"})
private Categories categories;
```

in the Result class

```
public class Result implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("FI")
    private String fi;
    @JsonProperty("event_id")
    private String eventId;
    
    @JsonProperty("categories")
    @JsonAlias({"cards", "corners"})
    private Categories categories;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -683759794150688410L;
```

How is the proper way to do this or do I have to create a class for each cards and corners object? This is just an example but in my real case I have like 20 of this objects.
I would also like to set the object key name to a variable since I want to map it against a field in the database.

I have tried and googled but not found what I am looking for or not really understood.
In the end I would like to save it to a table in a database like this:

| FI | event_id | category | updated_at | key | market_id | market | odds_id | odds | header | handicap | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FI value | event_id | value | "cards" | updated_at | AAA100 | cards.id | cards.name | odds.id | odds.odds | odds.header | odds.handicap |
|  |  |  | "corners" | AAA200 | corners.id | corners.name | odds.id | odds.odds | odds.header | odds.handicap | odds.name |
| Example |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 120986750 | 5164306 | cards | 1660559432 | AAA100 | 1 | Cards | 101 | 2.2 | Over |  | 11 |
| 120986750 | 5164306 | cards | 1660559432 | AAA100 | 1 | Cards | 102 | 8.5 | Exatly |  | 11 |
| 120986750 | 5164306 | cards | 1660559432 | AAA100 | 1 | Cards | 103 | 1.909 | Under |  | 11 |
| 120986750 | 5164306 | corners | 1660559431 | AAA200 | 2 | Corners | 201 | 2.2 | Over |  | 10 |
| 120986750 | 5164306 | corners | 1660559431 | AAA200 | 2 | Corners | 202 | 8.5 | Exatly |  | 10 |
| 120986750 | 5164306 | corners | 1660559431 | AAA200 | 2 | Corners | 203 | 1.909 | Under |  | 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is complicated to handle dynamic contents by defining many Classes. I suggest to transform the JSON directly using JSON query library. For example, use *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"success\": 1," +
    "    \"results\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"FI\": \"120986750\"," +
    "            \"event_id\": \"5164306\"," +
    "            \"cards\": {" +
    "                \"updated_at\": \"1660559432\"," +
    "                \"key\": \"AAA100\"," +
    "                \"sp\": {" +
    "                    \"cards\": {" +
    "                        \"id\": \"1\"," +
    "                        \"name\": \"Cards\"," +
    "                        \"odds\": [" +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"101\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"2.200\"," +
    "                                \"header\": \"Over\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"11\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"102\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"8.500\"," +
    "                                \"header\": \"Exactly\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"11\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"103\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"1.909\"," +
    "                                \"header\": \"Under\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"11\"" +
    "                            }" +
    "                        ]" +
    "                    }" +
    "                }" +
    "            }," +
    "            \"corners\": {" +
    "                \"updated_at\": \"1660559431\"," +
    "                \"key\": \"AAA200\"," +
    "                \"sp\": {" +
    "                    \"corners\": {" +
    "                        \"id\": \"2\"," +
    "                        \"name\": \"Corners\"," +
    "                        \"odds\": [" +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"201\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"2.200\"," +
    "                                \"header\": \"Over\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"10\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"202\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"8.500\"," +
    "                                \"header\": \"Exactly\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"10\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"203\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"1.909\"," +
    "                                \"header\": \"Under\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"10\"" +
    "                            }" +
    "                        ]" +
    "                    }," +
    "                    \"total_corners\": {" +
    "                        \"id\": \"3\"," +
    "                        \"name\": \"Total Corners\"," +
    "                        \"odds\": [" +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"204\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"17.000\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"Under 6\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"205\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"4.333\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"6 - 8\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"206\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"2.750\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"9 - 11\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"207\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"3.400\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"12 - 14\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"id\": \"208\"," +
    "                                \"odds\": \"5.500\"," +
    "                                \"name\": \"Over 14\"" +
    "                            }" +
    "                        ]" +
    "                    }" +
    "                }" +
    "            }" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "results.map(" +
    "    FI," +
    "    event_id," +
    "    categories: entries().[value.isObject()]*" +
    "        .map(category: key," +
    "             value.updated_at," +
    "             value.key," +
    "             details: value.sp.**" +
    "                 .map(market_id: id," +
    "                      market: name," +
    "                      odds)" +
    "                 .unwind(odds)" +
    "        ).unwind(details)" +
    ").unwind(categories)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
[ {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "cards",
  "updated_at" : "1660559432",
  "key" : "AAA100",
  "market_id" : "1",
  "market" : "Cards",
  "id" : "101",
  "odds" : "2.200",
  "header" : "Over",
  "name" : "11"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "cards",
  "updated_at" : "1660559432",
  "key" : "AAA100",
  "market_id" : "1",
  "market" : "Cards",
  "id" : "102",
  "odds" : "8.500",
  "header" : "Exactly",
  "name" : "11"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "cards",
  "updated_at" : "1660559432",
  "key" : "AAA100",
  "market_id" : "1",
  "market" : "Cards",
  "id" : "103",
  "odds" : "1.909",
  "header" : "Under",
  "name" : "11"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "corners",
  "updated_at" : "1660559431",
  "key" : "AAA200",
  "market_id" : "2",
  "market" : "Corners",
  "id" : "201",
  "odds" : "2.200",
  "header" : "Over",
  "name" : "10"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "corners",
  "updated_at" : "1660559431",
  "key" : "AAA200",
  "market_id" : "2",
  "market" : "Corners",
  "id" : "202",
  "odds" : "8.500",
  "header" : "Exactly",
  "name" : "10"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "corners",
  "updated_at" : "1660559431",
  "key" : "AAA200",
  "market_id" : "2",
  "market" : "Corners",
  "id" : "203",
  "odds" : "1.909",
  "header" : "Under",
  "name" : "10"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "corners",
  "updated_at" : "1660559431",
  "key" : "AAA200",
  "market_id" : "3",
  "market" : "Total Corners",
  "id" : "204",
  "odds" : "17.000",
  "name" : "Under 6"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "corners",
  "updated_at" : "1660559431",
  "key" : "AAA200",
  "market_id" : "3",
  "market" : "Total Corners",
  "id" : "205",
  "odds" : "4.333",
  "name" : "6 - 8"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "corners",
  "updated_at" : "1660559431",
  "key" : "AAA200",
  "market_id" : "3",
  "market" : "Total Corners",
  "id" : "206",
  "odds" : "2.750",
  "name" : "9 - 11"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "corners",
  "updated_at" : "1660559431",
  "key" : "AAA200",
  "market_id" : "3",
  "market" : "Total Corners",
  "id" : "207",
  "odds" : "3.400",
  "name" : "12 - 14"
}, {
  "FI" : "120986750",
  "event_id" : "5164306",
  "category" : "corners",
  "updated_at" : "1660559431",
  "key" : "AAA200",
  "market_id" : "3",
  "market" : "Total Corners",
  "id" : "208",
  "odds" : "5.500",
  "name" : "Over 14"
} ]
```

Comment: thank you. That looks really interesting. Need to look into this.

Comment: @Raymong Choi I have not managed to totally understand how solve my issue with josson. My example I had was an simple example. If you look at my json response now you can see that I under corners --> sp have two objects but when I use the code I got from you it only handles the first in each array.

Comment: @user982455 I have updated the query to handle multiple objects under `sp` according to your new dataset provided.

Comment: BIG THANK YOU. I will look thru your updated code and the first edit that I have saved and try to read into it more and understand.